# "Save as draft" option missing from the default message app?

Tags: sms, samsung-galaxy-y

I have a Samsung galaxy Y mobile phone, and I have just discovered that the option to save messages as draft is completely missing in the app named "Messaging" that I got pre-installed.

I am really shocked, as this is a very basic and common feature in the cheapest phones today.

My Question is: What kind of design/usage philosophy/idea/concept/thought is behind this?
Also, is their any good alternative to this pre-installed app which has the option to save drafts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stock messaging app will automatically save a draft message when you tap on the back button while composing the message, but the recipient field has to be filled. Without a recipient it will give a warning that the message will be deleted.

There are a lot of good alternatives. I have no experience with them myself (I'm using the stock app) but a lot of people seem to like [Handcent](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.handcent.nextsms), [GO SMS Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jb.gosms) or [ChompSMS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.p1.chompsms). Just search the Internet for reviews.

Answer (score 0):

Type the message as you want it to read, but in the **To:** box, type something to identify it as a draft, that is not the same value as anything in your address book.

Use *'draft'* or *'message to Jim'* or whatever identifies it for you. Then back out of the message.

Since it hasn't sent, your phone will save it as a draft, and it will appear in your list of messages. You can then open it at a later time, edit if desired, change the **To:** box to the recipient, and send when ready.